# Strange beavior with LayoutParams

Tags: android, layoutparams

I am currently playing around a bit with code generated Layouts.
There I recogniced a problem in this part of code:

```
dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int dp_x = (dm.widthPixels - 32) / 10;

for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
        i.setClickable(true);
        i.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(dp_x, dp_x));
        i.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.i0));
        iv[x][y] = i;
        tr.addView(iv[x][y]);
    }
    fieldLayout.addView(tr);
}
```

Especially this line seems to cause the problem:

```
i.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(dp_x, dp_x));
```

When this line is commented out everything is displayed correctly. But as soon as I uncomment it not a single one of the ImageViews is displayed.
I looked into debugging and every value seems to be added correctly to the ImageView.
Any Idea, what causes this error?

Another thing is - I know DisplayMetrics and their width/height are discouraged to use.
Here I use it to scale the ImageViews in dependence to the display. 
Can I achieve this in another way, too?

Comment: *Any Idea, what causes this error?* - always use the proper `LayoutParams`(the ones of the parent, `TableRow` in your case) instead of just `LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `dp_x` and `dp_y` values are correct :

```
TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(dp_x, dp_y);
i.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

It seems like it doesn't change anything but it worked for me ! Maybe because the LayoutParams are more specific (**TableRow**.LayoutParams)

Hope this helps !

Comment: Right, TableRow.LayoutParams() actually worked. Didn't know that I had to use the specific ones of the Parent...

Comment: Glad I could help ! I changed the LinearLayout to TableRow so the answer is more accurate.